# How to put value in HashMap?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a Map

```
Map<String,String[]> data = HashMap<String,String[]>();
```

and want to put value in it. like

```
"key":["value1","value2"]
```

I try it but get error:

```
data.put("key",["value1","value2"]);//syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the Array initializer for fixed size string arrays like following

```
    Map<String, String[]> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("key", new String[]{"val1", "val2"});
```

This should definitely work